# App crashes when clicking on any item with OnItemClickListener on array sort line

Tags: android, sorting, android-listview, crash, onitemclicklistener

App works well until i click on any list item, it crashes.When using search it works well, but when i click it directly on list item app stops.Logcat and and debug shows same problem on line 153.I coomented line 153.First code is CribActivity last one is view activity, i dont know maybe it is somehow related to this error.

```
 @SuppressLint("UseValueOf")
 public class CribActivity extends Activity 
 {
private ListView lv1;
private EditText et;

private String lv_arr[]={
        "item 1",
        "item 2",
        "item 67"
        };
private ArrayList<String> array_sort= new ArrayList<String>();
int textlength=0;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    
    
    lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);

    lv1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
   
    lv1.setAdapter(
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , lv_arr));
    lv1.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    
    
    et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
    {
                                                                    
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s,
    int start, int count, int after)
    {
  
    }
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s,
    int start, int before, int count)
    {
    textlength = et.getText().length();
    array_sort.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < lv_arr.length; i++)
    {
    if (textlength <= lv_arr[i].length())
    {
    if(et.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(
    (String)
    lv_arr[i].subSequence(0,
    textlength)))
    {
   array_sort.add(lv_arr[i]);
                                 }
                                   }
                                  }
    lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>
    (CribActivity.this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_sort));
    }
    });
    
    
    lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
                long id) {
            String name = array_sort.get(position); //***THIS IS THE LINE 153***
            for (int i = 0; i < lv_arr.length; i++) {
                
                    if (name
                            .equalsIgnoreCase(
                                    (String) lv_arr[i])) {
                        position = i; 
                        
                        break;
                    }
                
            }
            
        
            String itemname = new Integer(position).toString();

            Intent intent = new Intent();

            intent.setClass(CribActivity.this, ViewActivity.class);

            Bundle b = new Bundle();

            
            b.putString("defStrID", itemname);

            intent.putExtras(b);

            nt
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

**Debug:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: ru.tablica.sputnikovyh, PID: 24169
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
    at ru.tablica.sputnikovyh.CribActivity$2.onItemClick(CribActivity.java:153)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:318)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1159)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3136)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchUp(AbsListView.java:4064)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3822)
    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:12513)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3024)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2705)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:440)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1830)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3400)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:398)
    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12752)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5106)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4909)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4479)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4445)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4585)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4453)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4642)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4479)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4445)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4453)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7092)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7061)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7022)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7195)
    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:186)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

**logcat:**

```
    E/eglCodecCommon: GoldfishAddressSpaceHostMemoryAllocator: ioctl_ping failed for device_type=5, 
    ret=-1
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
    at ru.tablica.sputnikovyh.CribActivity$2.onItemClick(CribActivity.java:156)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:318)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1159)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3136)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4052)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

**ViewActivity**

```
     public class ViewActivity extends Activity {

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.view);




    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    String itemname = "n" + bundle.getString("defStrID");

    Context context = getBaseContext();


    String text = readRawTextFile(context, getResources().getIdentifier(itemname, "raw", "ru.tablica.sputnikovyh"));

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    String summary = "<!Doctype html><html><head><meta charset=utf-8></head><body>" + text + "</body></html>";
    myWebView.loadData(summary, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "utf-8");
}

public static String readRawTextFile(Context ctx, int resId)
{
    InputStream inputStream = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(resId);

    InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);
    String line;
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        while (( line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
            text.append(line);
            text.append('\n');
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
    return text.toString();
}
}
```

Comment: This error tell you that in array_sort there aren't items in this position, try to print your array_sort

Comment: String name = array_sort.get(position);
System.out.println(array_sort); like this?

Comment: before String name, use Log.d("my array: ", "+"+array_stort)

Comment: nothing changes( exact same logcat with debug

Answer (score 0):

you are accessing `array_sort` inside `onItemClick`, which is empty on start until you perform any search. thats why you have `OutOfBoundException`

when not in "search mode" your listener should access `lv_arr` array or use convenient method `adapter.getItem(position)` - you need to keep reference to adapter instance or use `listView.getAdapter().getItem(position)`. I see you are echanging adapters when in search mode so you can also echange `OnItemClickListener` (but it would be better to have one listener set at start which some logic handling both cases - usual list and filtered by search)

Comment: i tried to add this two lines of code before onItemClick, but now its not clickable at all, if (array_sort.size() <= 0) return; 
            if (lv_arr.length <=0) return;

Comment: you have very messy code, in one line you are checking `array_sort`, in next you are accessing `lv_arr` - these are not the same. clean up your code, read again my answer and you will get a fix. adding some `if`s without understanding what and when they are checked isn't a solution

Comment: thats why your code isn't working - `array_sort` is empty (when any sort performed) and you are accesing it in first line of `onItemClick` (`array_sort.get(position`). but next line is working on `lv_arr` - you clearly doesn't know on which array you should work and perform clicked item receving

Comment: Thank you for help, but seems like I am not as good expert as you, so I would appreciate if you will be more accurate with advice. What kind of code and where should I add?

Comment: replace `String name = array_sort.get(position);` to `String name = lv_arr.get(position);` this will make your code work when NO search performed, not a single character entered into `EditText`. I would advice you to remove `array_sort` completely (and all related lines) from your code and write again filtering feature. there are plenty of tutorials and your current code is just a mess... you should learn more about this feature (searching/filtering) and some basics how arrays work, I won't provide you exact code to copy/paste, because you won't learn anything and this isn't purpose of SP